# load event not working in vue 3 onMounted

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm updating my vue2 project to vue3. I used `load` event in many places in my project, but in vue3 this not working anymore. How can I use it?

I need this:

```html
<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    alert("Window Loaded");
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Move it outside `onMounted`.

Comment: window is not defined

Comment: I'm adding event listeners on onMounted successfully. Change your alert to console.log and you should see the log entry.

Comment: To confirm, I also have this problem. This used to work in vue2, but no longer in vue3. I can add listeners to other events (`scroll`, `resize`), but not `load`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import `onMounted` like in the [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted)?

```js
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    alert("Window Loaded");
  })
})
</script>
```